# How to write a validations for MySQL server database values using web service in android?

Tags: android, mysql, validation, server

In my android application,I am using soap web service to store and retrieve data's in MySQL server.
My question is in that time of retrieving, I have to check some conditions.for example,

name,id,employee number for the particular employee details has been stored in MySQL server database.
Again if i have to register the same name or a employee number,I have to show a toast like "already registered".

Its easy but if its a SQL Lite database its possible.

but in the MySQL server how to check MySQL server data's.

please help guys...

Answer (score 0):

expose rest API for all your interaction with server and its back-end. 
eg: have one rest API for checking if user name is already existing.

Comment: Thanks for the response,How about soap to expose because the whole project i am using these web service  only.

Comment: rest API is actually light weight than soap. Now a days people prefer simple rest API as the protocol normally used is only http. SOAP is more generic form and can be implemented on top of other protocols as well (more heavy than rest APIs).